# Setting environment variables on eclipse

Tags: eclipse, bash, macos, applescript

I have been looking up ways to create a launcher of sorts so that environment variables are set when I run the Eclipse app on mac.

When I run the app from terminal, the environment variables are properly set since the bash script has them; however, when I run the app directly, it doesn't have them. I have looked at automator and eclipse settings but cannot seem to find a simple way of doing it. This is important because when I do maven install, the paths are not correct. I could set environment variables every time I do run but that seems tedious. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have the .app call an executable loader script, which can set environment variables and call the executable binary. The script is placed in Contents/MacOS/.  If you swap names with the main exec. binary, Info.plist will already point to it, then call the renamed binary from the loader script.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash


cd "$(dirname "$0")" || exit 1

cwd="$(pwd)"
export VARIABLE=808
exec "${cwd}/myapp"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also add the environment to the `Info.plist` and use `lsregister` if you don't want to swap the executable (found at [SJGP software blog](http://sjgpsoft.blogspot.com/2018/10/eclipse-and-environment-variables-in.html)).

Add the following to the `Info.plist` file in the application bundle:

```
  <key>LSEnvironment</key>
  <dict>
    <key>GIT_SSH</key>
    <string>/usr/bin/ssh</string>
  </dict>
```

then run `lsregister` on the application:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Support/lsregister -v -f /Applications/Eclipse.app
```

Comment: This worked for me to set some env variables for gradle scripts, thx a lot! BTW, what does this `lsregister` command really do?